# Passing options from a newcommand to a another command (\includegraphics)

Tags: graphics, pgfkeys, key-value, ifthenelse

I'm making a command called `\seal` that uses the `\includegraphics` function. The command `\seal` has some `key=value` options of its own (`color`, `beamer`, `trimz`) and it must accept all options of `\includegraphics` so that it directly passes them to it. We may use `\seal` for a picture called `theimage` as follows:

```
\seal[width=2cm, color=red]{theimage}
```

which calls:

```
\includegraphics[width=2cm]{theimage}
```

Although I want to use all options in `\includegraphics`, the following code does it well for the `height` and `width` options.

```
% Declaring options for "seal"
\pgfkeys{
/seal/.is family, /seal,
% "seal" options
color/.estore in = \sealColor,
beamer/.estore in = \sealBeamer,
trimz/.estore in = \sealTrimz,
% "\includegraphics" options
height/.estore in = \sealHeight,
width/.estore in = \sealWidth,
}

% Declaring variables for the left side of "key=value"
\newcommand{\sealHeightL}{height}
\newcommand{\sealWidthL}{width}

% Declaring a command for storing the image
\newcommand{\theimage}{}

% Defining the \seal command
\newcommand{\seal}[2][]{%
    \pgfkeys{/seal, #1}%
    %
    % Makes the left side of "key=value" empty
    % if there's no value
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\sealHeight}{}}
        {\renewcommand{\sealHeightL}{}}
        {\renewcommand{\sealHeightL}{height}}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\sealWidth}{}}
        {\renewcommand{\sealWidthL}{}}
        {\renewcommand{\sealWidthL}{width}}%
    %
    % The \includegraphics command
    \renewcommand{\theimage}{\includegraphics[%
        \sealHeightL=\sealHeight,%
        \sealWidthL=\sealWidth,%
    ]{#2}%
    %
    % The other command (pay no attention to this)
    \othercommand{\sealColor}{\sealBeamer}{\sealTrimz}{\theimage}
}
```

The basic idea of this code is to make `\seal[width=2cm, color=red]{theimage}` call `\includegraphics[width=2cm, =]{theimage}`, and `\seal[color=red]{theimage}` call `\includegraphics[=, =]{theimage}`. This works because neither `\includegraphics[width=2cm, =]{theimage}` nor `\includegraphics[=, =]{theimage}` produce error messages. The last one is equivalent to calling `\includegraphics[]{theimage}`.

Now, although this code does the work very well, it returns two error messages when calling `\seal[height=2cm]{theimage}`:

```
Undefined control sequence. \seal[height=2cm]{theimage}
Package keyval Error: undefined. \seal[height=2cm]{theimage}
```

When calling `\seal{theimage}`, it returns the following messages repeated twice.

```
Undefined control sequence. \seal{theimage}
Package keyval Error: undefined. \seal{theimage}
```

I suppose this happens for the same reason that `\includegraphics[\empty = \empty,]{theimage}`, where `\newcommand{\empty}{}`, returns the following error message:

```
Package keyval Error: undefined. \includegraphics[\empty = \empty]{theimage}
```

Using an `\ifthenelse` command inside the (square) brackets of `\includegraphics` doesn't seem to work. It also seems to be mandatory that `=` be directly written inside the brackets, and not inside a command that is inside the brackets. I can think of the following strategies for addressing this problem:

1. Devising a completely different approach for passing options from `\seal` to `\includegraphics`. Currently, I don't have a clue as to what that approach might be.
2. Letting LaTeX know that this is not an error. Since I am new in LaTeX, I don't know how to do this. I also feel this cannot be a proper solution: if there is an error message something must be not in place. It could have actual consequences for the other options. However, I am open to be persuaded otherwise on this.
3. Defining `\seal` so that it uses two brackets for `key=value` options: one for its own options and the other for the `\includegraphics` options. In this way, it will pass the whole string of one of those brackets to `\includegraphics`. In this case, we would call `\seal[width=2cm][color=red]{theimage}` instead of `\seal[width=2cm, color=red]{theimage}`. I think this might be the most straightforward solution. The first version of `\seal` was a command of the form `\seal[includegraphicsOptions]{colorValue}{beamerValue}{trimzValue}{theimage}`, which passed the whole `includegraphicsOptions` string to `\includegraphics` returning no error whatsoever. Nevertheless, I don't know how to define `\seal` so that it has two brackets and, although I more than welcome a solution along these lines, I consider it a bit sub-optimal to my taste. (I'm more likely to be persuaded otherwise on this one.)

But ultimately, I am here because I do not know how to properly address this. I hope someone can suggest a solution.

**Note:** The only packages I am using/requiring for this command are `graphicx`, `pgfkeys` and `ifthenelse`. (Also `tikz`, which is not important for this question, and optionally the class `beamer`.)

**PS:** I'm sorry I couldn't make this question shorter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `.unknown` feature:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}

% Declaring options for "seal"
\pgfkeys{
  /seal/.is family, /seal,
  % "seal" options
  color/.estore in = \sealColor,
  beamer/.estore in = \sealBeamer,
  trimz/.estore in = \sealTrimz,
  .unknown/.code={%
    \edef\includegraphicssealoptions{\includegraphicssealoptions,\pgfkeyscurrentname=#1}%
  },
}

% Defining the \seal command
\newcommand{\seal}[2][]{%
  \def\includegraphicssealoptions{}%
  \pgfkeys{/seal,color=black,beamer=,trimz=,#1}%
  \edef\thesealimage{\noexpand\includegraphics[\includegraphicssealoptions]{#2}}%
  % The other command (pay no attention to this)
  \othercommand{\sealColor}{\sealBeamer}{\sealTrimz}{\thesealimage}
}

\newcommand{\othercommand}[4]{%
  \typeout{%
    sealColor=#1^^J%
    sealBeamer=#2^^J%
    sealTrimz=#3^^J%
    imagecommand=\unexpanded\expandafter{#4}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\seal[width=2cm, color=red]{theimage}

\seal[trimz=b,width=2cm,height=1cm,beamer=x,color=red]{theimage}

\end{document}
```

For inserting the image you issue `\thesealimage`, I guess in `\othercommand`.

With the definition in the example, you get

```latex
sealColor=red
sealBeamer=
sealTrimz=
imagecommand=\includegraphics [,width=2cm]{theimage}
```

and

```latex
sealColor=red
sealBeamer=x
sealTrimz=b
imagecommand=\includegraphics [,width=2cm,height=1cm]{theimage}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm studying your answer.

Comment: I tested your answer and it seems to be the right answer. Really thanks. I think I'll become a fan of the `.unknown` feature.

Answer (score 0):

This is (almost) trivial to do with `expkv-cs`. The following doesn't define your temporary macros and only works by argument forwarding (if you need macros like `\sealColor` to be defined you can do so in `\sealDO` before you pass them on to `\othercommand`).

The following uses the same `\othercommand` as @egreg and the same values (except it doesn't expand the first token of the image command, as that is already `\includegraphics`):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{expkv-cs}

\newcommand\seal[2][]{\sealKV{#1}{#2}}
\ekvcSplitAndForward\sealKV\sealDO
  {
     color  = {} % #1
    ,beamer = {} % #2
    ,trimz  = {} % #3
    ,...         % #4 -- all unknown keys
  }
\newcommand\sealDO[5]
  {\othercommand{#1}{#2}{#3}{\includegraphics[#4]{#5}}}

\newcommand{\othercommand}[4]{%
  \typeout{%
    sealColor=#1^^J%
    sealBeamer=#2^^J%
    sealTrimz=#3^^J%
    imagecommand=\unexpanded{#4}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\seal[width=2cm, color=red]{theimage}

\seal[trimz=b,width=2cm,height=1cm,beamer=x,color=red]{theimage}

\end{document}
```

which will print to the terminal:

```
sealColor=red
sealBeamer=
sealTrimz=
imagecommand=\includegraphics [, {width} = {2cm} ]{theimage}
sealColor=red
sealBeamer=x
sealTrimz=b
imagecommand=\includegraphics [, {width} = {2cm} , {height} = {1cm} ]{theimage}
```